# The proof of Kaplansky's threorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

I am reading "Commutative Ring theory" written by Matsumura.
I have a question about the proof of Kaplansky's theorem.

In Lemma 1, we construct a well-ordered family $\{F_{\alpha}\}$ such that (i)~(vi) hold.

Why does the well-ordered family $\{F_\alpha\}$ satisfy condition (ii), (i.e.) $\bigcup_{\alpha}F_\alpha= F$?

I appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry. I realized I was mistaken for Question 1.

Comment: Is it now possible to simplify your post? You should do that with the edit button, if so.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the successor step of the construction, it says to stop if $F=F_\beta$.  This is the only way the construction ever stops, so if it does stop, the final $F_\beta$ will be equal to $F$ itself and so trivially $\bigcup_\alpha F_\alpha=F$.

If the construction never stops, then it continues and $F_\alpha$ is defined for all ordinals $\alpha$.  Moreover, by construction $F_{\beta+1}$ is always strictly larger than $F_\beta$.  But this would then imply that $F$ is a proper class, since it has elements in $F_{\beta+1}\setminus F_\beta$ for every ordinal $\beta$.  So the construction must stop (and in fact it must stop at no later than $F_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the cardinality of $F$).